# Why SHA sum is different when calculated by python and linux command line program?

Tags: python, shell, sha

I used python to calculate sha sum of a string but output is different by two different programs.

Here is what I did:

```
~/$ echo "Tuwile@com.termux" | sha256sum
cc85269412339c15a992fb8766f5d1d6e0c2f0fbab990d4fc569d747503d98a2  -
~/$ python                                                                                          
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan  8 2021, 21:18:33)
[Clang 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> r=hashlib.sha256("Tuwile@com.termux".encode())
>>> print(r.hexdigest())
40445c42210abea6b0e681b29d15b163692826128c369834ab3b9e63ac8f6527
>>>
```

Comment: @AnthonySottile What about when I put the string in a file and the run `sha256sum $file` ? Problem is same

Comment: your file probably ends in a newline

Answer (score 4):

By default, `echo` adds the end of line `\n` to the output, and it becomes the part of the `sha256sum` input. Add the `-n` flag to suppress it:

```
>>> echo -n "Tuwile@com.termux" | sha256sum
40445c42210abea6b0e681b29d15b163692826128c369834ab3b9e63ac8f6527 -
```